# Any way possible to make different containers for Glide Disk Storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

In my android application, I am using a WebView and downloading (caching) the webpage assets into the internal storage of the device in the shouldInterceptRequest callback of the WebViewClient class. The basic code is below

```
        override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
            view: WebView,
            request: WebResourceRequest
        ): WebResourceResponse? {
  val file = Glide.with(view).downloadOnly().load(request.url).skipMemoryCache(true).submit().get()
return                 WebResourceResponse(
                    filesExtensionsToMimeTypes[extension],
                    "UTF-8",
                    inputStream
                )
}
```

The problem I facing is that Glide has limited internal disk storage (~250MB) and user has no control over that, like dividing it between two or more use cases as far as I know. Since Glide is used extensively in my android application, I am doubting myself that the internal storage will be very quickly filled since the user can then open subsequent webpages.

I thought about not using glide and downloading and managing the web assets on my own. But still I want to use Glide to make the process considerably easier.